# FirebaseTableViewDataSource crashes on user signout and signin

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

My app has a UITableViewController which uses a FirebaseTableViewDataSource (from FirebaseUI). The table shows the user's bookmarked posts correctly, but when I log that user off, and log another user in, the app crashes with the following message:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'***

I suspect the problem is related to how FirebaseUI updates the content of the tableView. I've being debugging this for the past 4 days; searched the SO questions; read the relevant docs but none mentions this unique issue. Any help will be much appreciated.

**The Details** (Sorry it's actually long)

This is my database structure:

```
|
+-posts
|   |
|   +-$postid
|        |
|        +-/* properties of a post: title, text, etc */
|
+-users
   |
   +-$userid
        |
        +-bookmarks
             |
             +-post1: true
             |
             +-post2: true
```

I am using FirebaseUI to show a user his/her bookmarks by passing the `users/$userid/bookmarks` ref to FirebaseTableViewDataSource as a query. Then for each key, I observe a single value event on `posts/$postid` in order to retrieve the post details...code below:

```
self.authStateListenerHandle = FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in

    guard let user = user else {
        return
    }

    self.query = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(user.uid).child("bookmarks")

    self.tableViewDataSource = FirebaseTableViewDataSource(query: self.query!, view: self.tableView, populateCell: { (tableView, indexPath, snapshot) -> UITableViewCell in

        if snapshot.exists() {

            let postRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(snapshot.key)

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: BookmarksVC.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MiniTableCell

            postRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                if snapshot.exists() {
                    let post = Event(snapshot: snapshot)!
                    let postVM = EventViewModel(post: post)
                    cell.populateCellWithEvent(postVM)
                    cell.delegate = self
                }
            })

            return cell
        }
        else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
    })

    self.tableView.dataSource = self.tableViewDataSource
}
```

I put the above code in viewDidAppear and then remove the authStateListenerHandle in viewWillDisappear like so

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if let handle = self.authStateListenerHandle {
        FIRAuth.auth()?.removeStateDidChangeListener(handle)
    }
}
```

Almost everything works fine except, when I am viewing the bookmarks for a user, then log out and log back in, the app crashes with the message

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
>       ***

Comment: In the `viewWillDisappear` set the `tableView.dataSource = nil`. So, that you don't update the dataSource improperly.

Comment: @Frank, thanks a lot! Setting `tableView.dataSource = nil` stopped the crash. However, it introduced another issue, the app now crashes when I do the following: go to the bookmarksVC, navigate to another VC, then add a child to the user's bookmarks node manually in Firebase console.

The message is something about `inserting 1 row into section 0 with 0 rows...`. Anyways, I solved the problem by setting `self.tableViewDataSource = nil` (because that's what my self.tableView.dataSource eventually gets set to). Everything now works properly.

Comment: @Frank, can you please shed more light on why I was experiencing the crash in the first place? I know `tableView.dataSource = nil` clears out the dataSource for a clean start, but wasn't this supposed to be done by FirebaseUI?

Comment: eyeezzi: I didn't answer, merely edited your question for readability. I hope @New16 can shed some light on the reason for the crash and why his comment helped.

Comment: Actually you are modifying the datasource in a improper way. So, you need to have the delete, update and insert operations to be recorded in your tableViewDataSource. So, once you are clearing the old user data you need to inform the dataSource that you deleted everything. When the new user comes again you need to do the insertion. This way you won't have this crash. Instead of doing lot of those steps, I just asked you to set it to nil.

Comment: Well, on FirebaseUI you may open a bug with Google.

Comment: @New16, thanks for your explanation, I might open a bug issue on FirebaseUI after collecting more data on reproducing the bug, for the meantime, your workaround works perfectly...please make it an answer and I'll accept it. For some reason I saw your first comment as Frank's, partly because he answers most Firebase questions here on SO...at least 90% of the ones I came across while researching my question. Thanks to you both for helping newbies like me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `viewWillDisappear` set the `self.tableViewDataSource = nil`. So, that you don't update the `dataSource` improperly.