# FirebaseUI table view crashes with 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have 3 table views within a tab controller, all of them are getting populated like this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.dataSource = self.notesTableView.bind(to: getQuery()) { tableView, indexPath, snap in

        let cell = self.notesTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellident", for: indexPath)
        let customCell = cell as! TextCell
        self.notesTableView.dataSource = self.dataSource
        self.notesTableView.delegate = self

        if let note = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "note").value as! String? {
            customCell.notesLabel.text = note
        } else {
            customCell.notesLabel.text = "Undefined"
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

When I am running the app on my phone and switch between the tabs, after some point I am always running into this exception:

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.

Furthermore, the console shows this, but I am not sure how to interpret this:

> *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3600.7.47/UITableView.m:1737

My question is if someone has an idea what the cause of this exception in relation to FirebaseUI might be. My guess is that it has to do with populating the tables.

Comment: What does the content of your `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` method look like?

Comment: @ToddKerpelman I don't have that method. This should be covered by the FirebaseUI library I think.

Answer (score 0):

In the `viewWillDisappear` set the `self.dataSource = nil`.

So, that you don't update the `dataSource` improperly.

from this question 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40519402)

from my experience, the safest way is in the `viewWillDisappear` set `self.dataSource.unbind()`